# ¿como asignar una imagen de forma dinamica con una variable?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo varias imagenes (0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ..., 9.jpg) en la carpeta drawable y tengo un boton en el cual quiero que se muestren las imagenes una a la vez de forma aleatoria, cada vez que oprimo el boton

La dificulta que tengo, es que en la linea **boton_02.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagen_boton)** aparece un error al compilar, no acepta la variable imagen_boton, que contiene el nombre de la imagen, he intentado varias cosas (comillas "imagen_boton", 'imagen_boton') pero sigue el error al compilar. ¿Cual puede ser el error?

De antemano gracias por sus sugerencias.

Saludos

```
    public void boton_imagen(View view) {

       String imagen_boton = "";

       Random r = new Random();
       int Low = 0;
       int High = 9;
       int Result = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

       imagen_boton = Integer.toString(Result);

       boton_02.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagen_boton);

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución a tu inconveniente, es corregir lo siguiente. Dentro de tu botón, haz lo siguiente:

```
//primero se crea un arreglo donde pondrás todas las imágenes que tengas
int[] imagenes = {R.drawable.imagenUno, R.drawable.imagenDos}; //y así hasta la cantidad de imágenes que tengas dentro de tu carpeta Drawable

//Luego haces tu operación Random
Random r = new Random();
int Low = 0;
int High = 9;
int Result = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

//ahora le asignas la función a tu botón
boton_02.setBackgroundResource(imagenes[Result]);
```

Con eso ya debería estar solucionado tu inconveniente